# Testing Accuracy is high compared actual output. How to increase the actual output accuracy?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, logistic-regression

My logistic predict model is giving me a training accuracy of 80% and testing accuracy of 79%.

Training Model Accuracy:0.8039535210772422
Testing Model Accuracy:0.7937496044721021

My confusion matrix give me these values:
[image]

Using hyper parameter tuning and printing my classification reports:

```
                  precision    recall  f1-score   support

           0       0.87      0.88      0.87    172299
           1       0.77      0.70      0.74     17321

   micro avg       0.85      0.85      0.85    189620
   macro avg       0.77      0.74      0.76    189620
weighted avg       0.85      0.85      0.85    189620
```

When i compare the results to actual data it i tested the prediction model on only 40% of the data matches. How could i improve my actual output.

This is my code any suggestions would be really helpful.

```
# Create the hyperparameter grid
c_space = np.logspace(-5, 8, 15)
log_param_grid = {'C': c_space, 'penalty': ['l1', 'l2']}

# Setup the GridSearchCV object: logReg_cv

logReg=LogisticRegression()
logReg_cv = GridSearchCV(logReg,log_param_grid,cv=5)

y=predict_pi.P_I
X=pd.get_dummies(X)
test=pd.get_dummies(test)

extra_cols_train = [i for i in list(test) if i not in list(X)]
extra_cols_test = [i for i in list(X) if i not in list(test)]


X = X.reindex(columns=X.columns.tolist() + extra_cols_train)
X[extra_cols_train] = 0

test = test.reindex(columns=test.columns.tolist() + extra_cols_test)
test[extra_cols_test] = 0

X_train,X_test,y_train,y_test=train_test_split(X,y,test_size=0.4,random_state=42)



logReg_cv.fit(X_train,y_train)
pred_pi=logReg_cv.predict(X_test)
test_pi=logReg_cv.predict(X_train)

print("Training Model Accuracy:{}".format(accuracy_score(y_train,test_pi)))
print("Testing Model Accuracy:{}".format(accuracy_score(y_test,pred_pi)))

print(confusion_matrix(y_test, pred_pi))
print(classification_report(y_test, pred_pi))
print("Tuned Logistic Regression Parameter: {}".format(logReg_cv.best_params_))
print("Tuned Logistic Regression Accuracy: {}".format(logReg_cv.best_score_))
```

Answer (score 0):

This may mean that your model is overfitting your training data. Have you done a EDA on your actual data to see if its behavior is what you expected and your training/testing data actually represents your actual data.

Is your training set a subset of your actual data? I would recommend train your model on your actual data entirely, use every bit of data you have for the training.

When you test your model, I would recommend using Cross Validation. When you do like 5 folds or 10 folds of training/testing on your data, you should have a decent model.